# How to view logs of container before restart

Tags: linux, docker, logging

I have a container which was restart 14 hours ago. The container is running since 7 weeks. I want to inspect the container logs during a certain interval. When i run below command, I see there is no output

```
docker container logs pg-connect --until 168h --since 288h
```

When i run below commands i only see logs since the container was restarted.

```
docker logs pg-connect
```

Any idea how to retrieve older logs for the container?

More info if helps

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS        PORTS     NAMES
9f08fb6fb0fb   kosta709/alpine-plus:0.0.2     "/connectors-restart…"   7 weeks ago   Up 14 hours             connectors-monitor
7e919a253a29   debezium/connect:1.2.3.Final   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 weeks ago   Up 14 hours             pg-connect
>
>
> docker logs 7e919a253a29 -n 2
2022-08-26 06:37:10,878 INFO   ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=relations-0} Committing offsets   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
2022-08-26 06:37:10,878 INFO   ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=relations-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
> docker logs 7e919a253a29 |head
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer is closed forcefully.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:766)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortIncompleteBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:753)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:279)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022-08-24 16:13:06,567 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=session-0} failed to send record to barclays.public.session:   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer is closed forcefully.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:766)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortIncompleteBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:753)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:279)
>
> ls -lart /var/lib/docker/containers/7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1/
total 90720
drwx------ 2 root root        6 Jul  1 10:39 checkpoints
drwx--x--- 2 root root        6 Jul  1 10:39 mounts
drwx--x--- 4 root root      150 Jul  1 10:40 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000230 Aug 24 16:13 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.9
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000163 Aug 24 16:13 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.8
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000054 Aug 24 16:16 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.7
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000147 Aug 24 16:42 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.6
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000123 Aug 24 16:42 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.5
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000019 Aug 24 16:42 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.4
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000159 Aug 24 16:42 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.3
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000045 Aug 24 16:42 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      199 Aug 25 16:30 hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       68 Aug 25 16:30 resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       25 Aug 25 16:30 hostname
-rw------- 1 root root     7205 Aug 25 16:30 config.v2.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1559 Aug 25 16:30 hostconfig.json
-rw-r----- 1 root root 10000085 Aug 25 16:31 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log.1
drwx--x--- 4 root root     4096 Aug 25 16:31 .
-rw-r----- 1 root root  2843232 Aug 26 06:38 7e919a253a296494b74361e258e49d8c3ff38f345455316a15e1cb28cf556fa1-json.log
```

Comment: Do you mean the container logs or do you want to see the application logs? In the second case, you could use shell in the container and search for the application logs.

Comment: What is difference?

Comment: It depends on the logging of the container and the application.

Comment: Both logs to sysout as checked.

Comment: Then you could connect to the running conntainer and check the syslogs.

Comment: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash` and then somethin like `cat /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [the official guide][1]:

````
The docker logs command batch-retrieves logs present at the time of execution.```

To solve this issue you should instrument the container software to log its output to a persistent (rotated if you want) log file.


  [1]: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/
````

Comment: So the logs are not persistent  across reboots/container restart?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, each container is allowed to generate a log file up to a default size on disk. Because of that, you may be able to see the latest logs just before restarting if it fits into the log file and doesn't exceed. So you can save logs into a temporary file and inspect it.

```
docker logs --since <starting_date> continer_id  >& logs.txt
```

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/#options) you can read more about `--since` flag